# How to find index of nearest value in double array?

Tags: c#, arrays

i have an array of increasing double values.
How can i find out the index of a given double?
Is there a "onboard" function in c# or do i have to create a custom loop?

Thx for help

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please provide a bit more info. What did you try? Where are you stuck? What data is your iput, what the expected output?

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: If not sorted, [`Array.FindIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=netframework-4.8). If sorted, [`Array.BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8). You say the values increase, therefore it's sorted and you can use binary search.

Comment: He said _array of increasing double values_. I understood it is sorted :)

Comment: The title also suggests you are looking for nearest value and not an actual value that is present in the list. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `list` is a list of `double`s and you want to find the one nearest to `target`:

```
var result = list
              .Select((d,i) => (d,i))
              .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.d-target))
              .First();
```

- take the list of doubles
- convert it to tuples: the double value and the index
- sort by absolute difference between the double from the list and the target
- get the first, which has the lowest difference = closest value

See in action : https://dotnetfiddle.net/qybj9X

But this ignores the helpful fact that the original list is already sorted.

Comment: very good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution, use Array.indexOf(arrayname, valuetosearch) it returns the index of the first appearance of the specified value, if there is nothing to match it returns -1.

```
        double i = 0.1;
        double[] arrayDoubles = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 };
        Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(arrayDoubles, i));
        //it will return 0
```

Comment: Problem: this only finds exact matches. And "exact" and "double" don't mix well ...